# Android Chromium Seed missing signature error when update Android WebView System to version 118

Tags: android

My name is Antonio and I am a developer. The reason for my contact is that I have the problem after my customers updated the "Android WebView System" application to version 118 (versions prior to this work normally). The problem is when I'm trying to convert HTML from a WebView into PDF it doesn't generate and the following errors appear in the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUDsz.png)

I'm using the PrintDocumentAdapter for this and it doesn't call the necessary callbacks, I think because of these errors above. When I uninstall this version everything goes back to normal, but this solution is not ideal because it is generating a lot of support as many customers are complaining.

I looked for a solution on the internet but none worked.

below is the code:

```
package android.print;

import static com.mylojastore.ui.screen.components.AppPDFViewerScreenKt.TAG_PDF_VIEW;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.io.File;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

/**
 * Converts HTML to PDF.
 * <p>
 * Can convert only one task at a time, any requests to do more conversions before
 * ending the current task are ignored.
 */
public class PdfConverter implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "PdfConverter";
    private static PdfConverter sInstance;

    private Context mContext;
    private String mHtmlString;
    private File mPdfFile;
    private PrintAttributes mPdfPrintAttrs;
    private boolean mIsCurrentlyConverting;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private PdfConverterCallBack callBack;

    private PdfConverter(PdfConverterCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    public static synchronized PdfConverter getInstance(PdfConverterCallBack callBack) {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new PdfConverter(callBack);

        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Executing the run() method.");
        mWebView = new AdvancedWebView(mContext);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                PrintDocumentAdapter documentAdapter = mWebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
                documentAdapter.onLayout(null, getPdfPrintAttrs(), null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
                }, null);
                documentAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES}, getOutputFileDescriptor(), null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Executing the onWriteFinished() method.");
                        callBack.onWriteFinished();
                        destroy();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onWriteCancelled() {
                        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Writing PDF was cancelled");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onWriteFailed(CharSequence error) {
                        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Write HTML to PDF failed. Error --> "+ error.toString());
                    }

                });
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Loading HTML using encoding UTF-8");
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mHtmlString,"text/html; charset=utf-8","UTF-8", null);
    }

    public PrintAttributes getPdfPrintAttrs() {
        return mPdfPrintAttrs != null ? mPdfPrintAttrs : getDefaultPrintAttrs();
    }

    public void setPdfPrintAttrs(PrintAttributes printAttrs) {
        this.mPdfPrintAttrs = printAttrs;
    }

    public void convert(Context context, String htmlString, File file) {
        if (context == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("context can't be null");
        if (htmlString == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("htmlString can't be null");
        if (file == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file can't be null");

        if (mIsCurrentlyConverting)
            return;

        mContext = context;
        mHtmlString = htmlString;
        mPdfFile = file;
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = true;
        Log.d(TAG_PDF_VIEW,"Will run runOnUiThread method");
        runOnUiThread(this);
    }

    private ParcelFileDescriptor getOutputFileDescriptor() {
        try {
            mPdfFile.createNewFile();
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(mPdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE | ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private PrintAttributes getDefaultPrintAttrs() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return null;

        return new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_GOVT_LETTER)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
                .build();

    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    private void destroy() {
        mContext = null;
        mHtmlString = null;
        mPdfFile = null;
        mPdfPrintAttrs = null;
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = false;
        mWebView = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the only thing I saw at console:

chromium  [1110/113456.244286:ERROR:variations_seed_loader.cc(37)] Seed missing signature.
chromium  [1110/113456.244825:ERROR:variations_seed_loader.cc(69)] Failed to open file for reading. Errno: 2

The temporary solution we found was to ask customers to uninstall Android WebView System updates, the PDFs are generated again but this is not the ideal solution because many customers are complaining and this generates a huge influx in Support for our app.